# Pandas, numpy.where(), and numpy.nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I want to use [numpy.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to add a column to a pandas.DataFrame. I'd like to use NaN values for the rows where the condition is false (to indicate that these values are "missing").

Consider:

```
>>> import numpy; import pandas
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4]}); print(df)
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
>>> df['B'] = numpy.nan
>>> df['C'] = numpy.where(df['A'] < 3, 'yes', numpy.nan)
>>> print(df)
   A   B    C
0  1 NaN  yes
1  2 NaN  yes
2  3 NaN  nan
3  4 NaN  nan
>>> df.isna()
       A     B      C
0  False  True  False
1  False  True  False
2  False  True  False
3  False  True  False
```

Why does B show "NaN" but C shows "nan"? And why does [DataFrame.isna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) fail to detect the NaN values in C?

Should I use something other than numpy.nan inside where? `None` and `pandas.NA` both seem to work and can be detected by DataFrame.isna(), but I'm not sure these are the best choice.

Thank you!

Edit: As per @Tim Roberts and @DYZ, numpy.where returns an array of type string, so the str constructor is called on numpy.NaN. The values in column C are actually strings "nan". The question remains, however: what is the most elegant thing to do here? Should I use `None`? Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.where` coerces the second and the third parameter to the same datatype. Since the second parameter is a string, the third one is converted to a string, too, by calling function `str()`:

```
str(numpy.nan)
# 'nan'
```

As the result, the values in column C are all strings.

You can first fill the NaN rows with `None` and then convert them to `np.nan` with `fillna()`:

```
df['C'] = numpy.where(df['A'] < 3, 'yes', None)
df['C'].fillna(np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

B is a pure numeric column.  C has a mixture of strings and numerics, so the column has type "object", and it prints differently.

Comment: It does not _print_ differently. It _is_ different.